# Best practice for bumping your version number in an automated build system?

Tags: tfs, build, msbuild, automation, versioning

My build system (Team Foundation Server 2015) does the following:

- Get latest
- Un-shelve developer changes
- ***Check-out version file***
- ***Modify version file***
- ***Check-in modified version file***
- Run build/unit test
- Check-in developer changes (on successful build/test run)

My issue with this method is that the build agent is modifying a file and checking that change in. To me this feels dirty.

So is there a better way of doing this, is this really best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, it's better to put version information in a version control system, not in a file. I haven't worked with TFS, but in my work I use Git and put version information in git tags. Using the git describe command you can get the information about the latest tag, a number of commits since the last tag and hash of the last commit. It also can provide you with information about uncommitted changes in your working copy. 
All this information gives you the ability to distinguish one version of a binary from another.
And you don't have to create meaningless commits inside your repository.

Comment: So the version file is kept in source control, but I guess you mean storing the version number as some meta data. We can do this by 'labeling' our source control. 

Thanks, good to know that I am heading down a sensible path.

Comment: Yes, exactly! Tags in Git is a kind of labels.